# Sustituir pdf 'en uso' en iframe javascript c#

Tags: javascript, c#

tengo una aplicación web que muestra un archivo pdf en un iframe

los pdf que muestro en el iframe los busco en una ruta especifica, se lo muestro al usuario para que este decida si lo quiere sustituir por otro o no.

Si lo quiere sustituir simplemente presiona un botón y la aplicación lo sustituye por otro.

El problema es que al intentar sustituirle me dice que el archivo esta en uso.

No me sirve guardarlo con otro nombre porque varios departamentos dentro de la empresa lo buscan por ruta y nombre, si le cambio el nombre no lo van a ver.

El iframe es este:

```
 <iframe id='frameBefore' src="404.aspx" width="500" height="400" style="position: relative; width: 30%"></iframe>
```

El Copy lo hago desde C#:

```
 File.Copy(rutaArchivo, RUTA_COPIA_LOCAL,true);
```

La solucion mas sencilla sería abrir el pdf en el iframe de forma 'no exclusiva' pero no he conseguido forma de hacerlo.

Otra opción sería antes de mostrar el pdf, guardalo en otra ruta y mostrar esa copia en el iframe... pero no se hacerlo desde javascript (tendría que hacerlo desde javascript porque es desde donde le mando la ruta al iframe)

Comment: Que tecnologia utilizas? MVC o WebForms? Tambien agrega el codigo de como muestras el pdf para poder darte una respuesta completa.

Comment: Hola Einer, uso WebForms, para mostrar el pdf uso: $("#frameBefore").attr("src", ruta);

Comment: Luis, me referia al codigo que utilizas retornar el archivo desde el servidor.

Comment: Me falto explicar que aunque es una aplicación web, solo se usará dentro de la red de la oficina, por lo que apunto el src del iframe directamente a un archivo en el servidor (al que todos los usuarios tienen acceso)

Comment: Hay es donde esta el problema. No puedes apuntar directamente al archivo ya que si dira que esta en uso. Tienes que retornar el archivo desde el servidor evitando abrir el archivo varias vecces.

Comment: Bueno por ahora tendré que solucionar creando una copia del archivo, pero lo tendré que hacer en el back-end, por lo que tendré que recargar toda la pagina. Si logro recargar solo el iframe (cosa que se  me ha complicado) publicare la solucion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Me falto explicar que aunque es una aplicación web, solo se usará
>   dentro de la red de la oficina, **por lo que apunto el src del iframe
>   directamente a un archivo en el servidor** (al que todos los usuarios
>   tienen acceso)

Ese es el problema. Como apuntas al archivo directamente, el navegador lo lee y lo ocupa. Lo que necesitas es retornar una copia del archivo desde el servidor en vez cargar el archivo en si.

Intenta creando una pagina que reciba como parámetro la ruta del archivo, entonces utilizando el objeto `Response` retornas el contenido del archivo sin bloquearlo:

```
public class PDFViewer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                if(Request["filename"] != null)
                {
                    var fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(Request["filename"]);

                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; // le indicamos que sera un pdf
                    Response.BinaryWrite(fileContent); // le pasamos el contenido del pdf a mostrar
                    Response.Flush(); // liberamos la respuesta
                    Response.End(); // finalizamos la respuesta
                }


        }

}
```

Entonces en tu iframe ahora solo tendras editar la ruta y agregar la ruta de la pagina `PDFViewer`:

```
<iframe src="PDFViewer.aspx?filename=c:/pdf/nombrearchivo.pdf">
</iframe>
```

Asi no estarás cargando el archivo como tal, sino una copia del archivo.